# Dropwizard/Jersey - missing dependency for public method when running tests

Tags: jersey, dropwizard

I've encountered "Missing dependency" exception when running resourceTest using Dropwizard: 0.6.1 (jersey 1.15), has anybody had experience on this case?

**My test file**:

```
public class MyResourceImplTest extends ResourceTest {
   ........
    @Override
    protected void setUpResources() throws Exception {
        addResource(new MyResourceImpl(new myConfiguration()));
    }
}
```

**Exception**:

```
Dec 13, 2012 2:10:41 PM com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.inmemory.InMemoryTestContainerFactory$InMemoryTestContainer <init>
INFO: Creating low level InMemory test container configured at the base URI http://localhost:9998/
Dec 13, 2012 2:10:42 PM com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.inmemory.InMemoryTestContainerFactory$InMemoryTestContainer start
INFO: Starting low level InMemory test container
Dec 13, 2012 2:10:42 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.15 10/30/2012 02:40 PM'
Dec 13, 2012 2:10:42 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput com.****************.********(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) at parameter at index 0
Dec 13, 2012 2:10:42 PM com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.inmemory.InMemoryTestContainerFactory$InMemoryTestContainer stop
INFO: Stopping low level InMemory test container
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm stuggeling with something similar

Comment: Yes, my problem was that, I injected a HttpServletRequest which is supported by InMemory container, you need to use jetty grizzlyWebTestContainer or jetty in this case. But at the end of day, I ended up writing a integration tests using python to test my web services. It turns out way much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that, I injected a HttpServletRequest which is supported by InMemory container, I'd need to use jetty grizzlyWebTestContainer or jetty as the test contatiner in this case. I didn't quite get that working neither, because introducing in jersey-test-framework-grizzly did bring a lot of dependency conflicts against dropwizard itself. I recon it's not worthwhile trying to resolve all the conflicts, because when I upgrade dropwizard in the future, this might happen again.

At the end of day, I ended up having a jenkins job with some integration tests(in python) to test my web services. eg. after the deployment, fire in some http requests, check the response code and response content. It turns out way much easier.

Answer (score 2):

**Looks like Jersey is not able to inject a `HttpServletRequest`**

Is one of your endpoints configured like this?

```
public StreamingOutput something(@Context HttpServletRequest request, String a, String b) {}
```

If so, you may want to rethink your design, and opt instead for

```
@Context
private HttpContext context;

public StreamingOutput something(String a, String b) {

  System.out.println("Request info "+context.getRequest().getAbsolutePath());

}
```

which may yield a cleaner approach. So long as you rely on the `Class` resource registration then you're guaranteed a new instance per request which should avoid threading issues.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that HttpServletRequest can't be injected. But in my case, I want to get the request attribute by calling HttpServletRequest.getAttribute("blabla") which doesn't seem provided by HttpContext.

Comment: Not sure if it will help you, but there is some discussion about attribute extraction here: http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Why-doesn-t-HttpRequestContext-expose-request-attributes-td3953625.html

Comment: I have the same problem. Anyone fixed this already? I'm also doing some blabla(@Context HttpServletRequest request,...) and it works, but in tests it fails. If I use HttpContext, then I need the header set by servlet filter. How can I get this header out of HttpContext interface ? Any ideas?

Comment: You probably want to use `HttpHeaders`. See [BaseResource](https://github.com/gary-rowe/MultiBitMerchant/blob/develop/mbm-platform/src/main/java/org/multibit/mbm/client/interfaces/rest/resources/BaseResource.java) for an example. The overall project there uses Dropwizard so may answer other questions you may encounter as well (e.g. using HAL)

Answer (score 0):

The way I got around this was to define an abstract base-class resource without the context injected, and then implement a tiny derived class for your real service.

```
@Path("/contextMethod")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MyResourceWithContext extends BaseResource {
    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    protected String getUserID()
    {
        return request.getRemoteUser();
    }
}
```

When you run your tests, you then implement an alternate derived class just for testing, which doesn't use the HttpServletRequest. The bonus advantage here is that your derived testable class can injext (say) a hardcoded value for the context to create some suitable test scenarios.